# Processing the file problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in a ruby learning book .I face this code :

```
f = File.new("a.txt", "r")
while a = f.getc
    puts a.chr
    f.seek(5, IO::SEEK_CUR)
end
```

author writes that this code produce every fifth character in a file, but I don't understand why? please explain me line by line.
thanks.

Comment: In my opinion ' every fifth character in a file' is wrong. With f.getc you read one character, then you skip 5 characters. Then you read the next one... so you get each sixth character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = File.new("a.txt", "r")
```

This line opens the file in read mode and keeps the file object(as an I/O(Input/Output) stream) in variable f. (See [File#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000070))

```
while a = f.getc
```

`getc` is a method of class IO which gets one character of the I/O stream at a time and it will give `nil`, when it meets the end of the I/O stream. So `while a = f.getc` will loop until the end of file. (See [IO#getc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000922))

```
puts a.chr
```

`f.getc` will give the ASCII value of the character and inorder to get the character from the ASCII value, we apply `a.chr`(See [Integer#chr](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Integer.html#M000289)). I think in Ruby 1.9, we will get the character itself as the output of `getc`, but for earlier versions, we get the ASCII value as the output. The first `getc` command reads the first character and moves the position of I/O stream after the first character.

```
f.seek(5, IO::SEEK_CUR)
```

`seek` is a method of I/O stream which changes the position of the I/O stream by an offset of the first parameter from the second parameter. `IO::SEEK_CUR` is a constant which gives the current position of the I/O stream. So `f.seek(5, IO::SEEK_CUR)` moves the position to 5 places from the current position. (See [IO#seek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000931))

This will continue till `a = f.getc` becomes a false condition(here at the end of file, `f.getc` becomes `nil`, which is a falsey value in Ruby(`false` and `nil` are the only falsy values in Ruby, all others are truth values))

Use IRB to study and experiment with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

`a = f.getc; puts a.chr` outputs a single character; `f.seek(5, IO::SEEK_CUR)` moves forward by 5 characters.